# How to rename files and change the file type as well?

Tags: python, excel, csv, rename, dbf

I have a list with `.dbf` files which I want to change to `.csv` files. By hand I open them in excel and re-save them as `.csv`, but this takes too much time.

Now I made a script which changes the file name, but when I open it, it is still a `.dbf` file type (although it is called `.csv`). How can I rename the files in such a way that the file type also changes?

My script uses (the dbf and csv file name are listed in a seperate csv file):

```
IN = dbffile name
OUT = csvfile name

for output_line in lstRename:
    shutil.copyfile(IN,OUT)
```

Comment: Simply changing the filename will not do anything to the contents of the file. When you do a "Save As" in Excel, it's actually changing the format the file is saved in, in addition to the name.

Comment: Converting DBF files to CSV sounds like "escaping out of the frying pan into the fire" to me; you lose all type (number, character, date, boolean, NULL) information. What is the consumer of these CSV files? If it's a spreadsheet app or a database load, you'd be better going directly ... use a DBF-reading Python module to get properly-typed data a row at a time, perform any necessary manipulations, and use a target specific Python module for output.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the name of a file (and the extension is just part of the complete name) has absolutely no effect on the contents of the file.  You need to somehow convert the contents from one format to the other.

Using [my dbf module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) and [python](http://python.org) it is quite simple:

```
import dbf

IN = 'some_file.dbf'
OUT = 'new_name.csv'

dbf.Table(IN).export(filename=OUT)
```

This will create a `.csv` file that is actually in csv format.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ever used VB or looked into VBA, you can write a simple excel script to open each file, save it as csv and then save it with a new name.

Use the macro recorder to record you once doing it yourself and then edit the resulting script.

I have now created a application that automates this.  Its called [xlsto](https://github.com/tobya/DocTo) (look for the xls.exe release file).  It allows you to pick a folder and convert all xls files to csv (or any other type).

Comment: that sounds good, but unfortunately I never used VB (Python is my first attempt to program something :))..

Comment: Well for this, you need to automate excel and VBA is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: There are other ways besides Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a converter

Search for [`dbf2csv`](http://www.google.de/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=dbf2cdv) in google.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. It seems like you want to convert files to other types. There are many converters out there, but a computer alone doesn't know every file type. For that you will need to download some software. If all you want to do is change the file extension,
(ex. .png, .doc, .wav) then you can set your computer to be able to change both the name and the extension. I hoped I helped in some way :)

Answer (score -1):

descargar libreria dbfpy desde http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfpy/?source=dlp

```
import csv,glob
from dbfpy import dbf

entrada = raw_input(" entresucarpetadbf ::")


lisDbf = glob.glob(entrada + "\\*dbf")
for db in lisDbf:
    print db
    try:
        dbfFile = dbf.Dbf(open(db,'r'))
        csvFile = csv.writer(open(db[:-3] + "csv", 'wb'))

        headers = range(len(dbfFile.fieldNames))

        allRows = []
        for row in dbfFile:
            rows = []
            for num in headers:
                rows.append(row[num])
            allRows.append(rows)

        csvFile.writerow(dbfFile.fieldNames)
        for row in allRows:
            print row
            csvFile.writerow(row)

    except Exception,e:
        print e
```

Answer (score -2):

It might be that the new file name is "xzy.csv.dbf".  Usually in C# I put quotes in the filename. This forces the OS to change the filename.  Try something like "Xzy.csv" in quotes.

Comment: A dbf is not formatted in the same way as csv, so you need to convert it as @HerrSerker states.

Comment: I will try that also, because actually all my colleagues should be albe to run the script (without downloading extra converters).

Comment: So i am afraid I will need dbfpy (and let all my colleagues know they have to download it..