# how can I create a new .dbf file with python (solution with ethanfurman/dbf package will be preferred)

Tags: python, dbf

I couldn't find any public method in [ethanfurman/dbf](https://github.com/ethanfurman/dbf) for writing data to a given file path instead of modifying an existed file. I wanna create a dbf file from a list of tuple and the "field_specs" string.

In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168223/how-to-rename-files-and-change-the-file-type-as-well/8187072#8187072) the author mentioned dbf.Table.export() but I cannot find it from current version of lib.

Comment: `export` is for creating a `csv` file, not a `dbf` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a table:

```
import dbf

new_table = dbf.Table('new_file_name.dbf', 'field1 C(10); field2 N(5,2)')
```

and to write records to it (or any open table in read/write mode):

```
new_table.open(dbf.READ_WRITE)

# using tuples
new_table.append(('a value', 27.31))

# using a dictionary
new_table.append({'field1':'a value', 'field2': 27.31})
```

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the meaning of "on_disk", I really appreciate your dedicated coding.

Comment: Using that line 
new_table = dbf.Table('new_file_name.dbf', 'field1 C(10), field2 N(5,2)')
ended up in:
dbf.FieldSpecError: Format for Character field creation is 'C(n)', not 'C (10), FIELD2 N(5,2)' (new_file_name.dbf:FIELD1)
... but there is no space inbetween?!
(this happened with version 0.99.3)

Comment: @OrangMutan: you need to use a semi-colon (`;`), not a comma, between field definitions.  So `'field1 C(10); field2 N(5,2)'`.